# Ajax calendar control not showing all dates in asp.net . it is showing up to 20th date only

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ajax calendar does not showing all dates in my asp.net page

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurchaseDate" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPurchaseDate" runat="server" Height="18px" 
      ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" Width="18px" CssClass="TopMargin" />
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
      TargetControlID="txtPurchaseDate" PopupButtonID="btnPurchaseDate"
      Format="MM/dd/yyyy" CssClass="cal_Theme1">
 </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Is that my css problem or asp design problem

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Do you set `EndDate` extender's property?

Comment: .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_container{background-color: #e2e2e2; 
border:solid 1px #cccccc;}
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_header{background-color: #ffffff; 
margin-bottom: 4px;}
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_title,.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_next,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_prev{color: #004080; padding-top: 3px;
}.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_body{background-color: #e9e9e9; 
border: solid 1px #cccccc;}

Comment: .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_dayname {text-align:center; 
font-weight:bold;margin-bottom: 4px; 
margin-top: 2px;}.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_day {
text-align:center;}
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_active  {color: #004080; font-weight: bold;background-color: #ffffff;}.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_today   {font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_other,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_title {
color: #bbbbbb;}

Comment: No... how to set that enddate property

Comment: when i set StartDate and Enddate property it shows an error msg as Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'StartDate'

Comment: which version of AjaxControlToolkit you use?